# Badge suggestion: Eternal Question / Eternal Answer

Tags: feature-request, up-votes, badge-request

Sometimes I vote up questions or answers and I get a tooltip saying "you already voted up on date [years ago]...".

I think that questions and answers who get repeated votes in the long term deserve a badge.

I propose "**Eternal question**" or "**Eternal answer**" badge awarded to questions and answers voted up by (say) 50 distinct users that already voted up for it at least 1 year ago. 
It could be scaled on bronze, silver and gold accordingly with the quantity of users and elapsed time between the repeated votes.

Comment: umm... the "you already voted up on date [years ago]." is error message, it's not recorded anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt many people would earn this badge organically. Most users know they can't upvote a post twice, and even if they don't, it's clear after the first attempt and they won't try it on another post (unless it's "for science"); you can actually *see* if you voted for a post because the button is colored. So in the end, very few posts will be 'doubly upvoted' twice or more.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, I got today 2 "you already voted". It is not the first time it happens, and of course I know that double vote is not possible. It is true that the arrow has a different color, but I often fail noticing it. So I think that those questions or answers must be really good. Probably other users pay more attention to the color of the arrow; anyway, if you do not record those "double votes" it is not possible to know how many times this happens. On the other hand you could say that I keep searching for the same topics and I should learn the answer once for all.

Comment: What also can happen is that you see a good answer to your problem, try to upvote it and get the message that you can't vote for your own posts...